# how to replace url path in html file

Tags: php, regex

How to find and replace all URL paths in an HTML file? I have an HTML file with links from Wayback Machine, like these:

```
"/web/2016***/http://blog.mydomain.com/archive/img.jpg"    
"/web/2016***/http://blog.mydomain.com/archive/img2.jpg"
"/web/2016***/http://blog.mydomain.com/archive/page2.html"
```

The `2016***` part is dynamic. How do I extract these elements:

```
"/archive/img.jpg"
"/archive/img2.jpg"
"/archive/page2.html"
```

I have tried:

```
$html = $url;
$content = file_get_contents($html);
$newhtml = preg_replace( 'web/-[^-.]*\./' , '/' , $content);
file_put_contents('post1.html', $newhtml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression: `\/web.*blog\.mydomain\.com(.*)`:

```
preg_replace('\/web.*blog\.mydomain\.com(.*)', '\1', $content);
```

Check it out in action: https://regex101.com/r/m5ZaRo/3

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash